# Finding correct shift based on time in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 8 hrs shifts like this in my table `Shift` and `shiftstart` and `shiftend` datatype as `time(7)`.

```
ShiftNo ShiftName  ShiftStart  ShiftEnd  IsNextDay  IsBothNextDay
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    Shift1     7:00:00     14:59:59   0          0
   2    SHift2     15:00:00    22:59:59   0          0
   3    Shift3     23:00:00    7:00:00    1          0
```

If I execute the procedure at 07:10, I should get shift3 row

```
23:00:00.0000000-07:00:00.0000000 as timestamp
```

My existing procedure is

```
DECLARE @Currentdate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @Currenttime AS TIME
DECLARE @PreviousShifttime AS TIME

SET @Currentdate = GETDATE()
PRINT @currentdate  

SET @Currenttime = (SELECT CAST(@Currentdate AS TIME))
PRINT @Currenttime  

SET @PreviousShifttime = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -8, @Currentdate))
PRINT @PreviousShifttime  

SELECT 
    ShiftNo, ShiftName, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd, IsNextDay, IsBothNextDay 
FROM
    ShiftInfo
WHERE
    @PreviousShifttime BETWEEN ShiftStart AND ShiftEnd
```

This procedure is not returning the expected output when I want to get the row of shift 3. Output for this case is blank

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `Shift 3` starts at `23:00` till `07:00`. So the `WHERE` condition `where @PreviousShifttime between ShiftStart and ShiftEnd` will never be true.

Comment: @Squirrel but my previous shift time in this case is 23:10:00.000  so it should get shift 3 row

Comment: @ssd  between begin_expression and end_expression. You 'begin' (23:00) is bigger than your 'end' (7:00). How is that possible?

Comment: @GenWan I got it thanks for information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert to datetime for comparison. for shift 3, the ending shift time become the next day

```
declare @shift table
(
    shiftno     int,
    shiftstart  time(7),
    shiftend    time(7)
)

--  sample data
insert into @shift values
(1, '07:00', '14:59:59'),
(2, '15:00', '22:59:59'),
(3, '23:00', '07:00:00')

declare @Currenttime    as time

set @Currenttime = '06:30'

--  the query
; with shifts as
(
    select  *, 
        shift_start = convert(datetime, shiftstart),
        shift_end   = case  when shiftstart < shiftend
                    then convert(datetime, shiftend)
                    else dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, shiftend))
                    end
    from    @shift
)
select  *
from    shifts
where   convert(datetime, @Currenttime) between shift_start and shift_end
or       dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, @Currenttime)) between shift_start and shift_end
```

EDIT : to get the previous shift based on `@Currenttime`, use the following query

```
--  the query
; with 
shifts as
(
    select  *, 
        shift_start = convert(datetime, shiftstart),
        shift_end   = case  when shiftstart < shiftend
                    then convert(datetime, shiftend)
                    else dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, shiftend))
                    end
    from    @shift
),
current_shift as
(
    select  PrevShiftTime = dateadd(minute, -1, shiftstart)
    from    shifts
    where   convert(datetime, @Currenttime) between shift_start and shift_end
    or       dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, @Currenttime)) between shift_start and shift_end
)
select  *
from    shifts s
    cross join current_shift c
    where   convert(datetime, PrevShiftTime) between shift_start and shift_end
    or       dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, PrevShiftTime)) between shift_start and shift_end
```

Comment: how should I bind date in shift_start and shift_end column.currently it is 1900-01-01

Comment: the purpose of `shift_start` and `shift_end` is such that you will be able to handle the case when the `shiftend` is the next day. It is mean as internal to the query. For display purpose, you should still use your original column

Comment: one more thing SET @PreviousShifttime = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -8, @Currentdate)) I am doing this for finding previous shift but this hardocded how can I remove this based on closest time before current time?

Comment: `-8` hours should be fine. As your shift is 8 hours per shift

Comment: but I want to remove it beoz its not that case every  time shift will be  8 hrs

Comment: this query will give you the start of the shift based on `@Currenttime`. To get the `@PreviousShifttime`  just  minus 1 minute `dateadd(minute, -1, start of shift)`

Comment: i have edited the answer to add the extra query to get previous shift